# What are the best ways to integrate centralized login through Facebook app? on various platform

Tags: java, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I am creating a product which extends across various platforms like Android, IOS, Windows 8 and Web(Future release)

I was struggling to create a way to create a centralized login to facebook across various platforms .

For Ex :

If I have authorized my appA from my Facebook account on my Android Phone , then when i pick up my iPad I donot want to authorize the app again . It should know that the same FB account has been authorized once and should directly allow the app to fetch the required informations from Facebook - which i guess is not possible if we use the facebook sdk for IOS and android seperately

Now Incase I handle all facebook requests through a server which is hosted a lets say http://zbcdef.com and all my clients request this server to fetch the facebook related transactions.In such case how can my app fetch the information of the user logged in the facebook app on the device by default when the users log-in the the app (for ex like quora does it ) and how does it affect the mobile marketing campaigns analytics